# Is there a package that allows saving a terminal instance?

Tags: command-line, apt, ssh, python

Is there a package of some sort for saving a terminal instance like this:

`some_package instance_name python3.9 main.py`

*closes terminal*

`some_package instance_name`

*Shows the all terminal mesage as if I never closed it.*

I'm ssh-ing to the machine and sometimes, I have to leave with my laptop and this cause the connection to break so I can't see the terminal, is there a package that can save the instance so I can just call it again and it will show me the output again?

Thanks.

Comment: install `screen`  and you can reconnect to it with `screen -dr` after you reconnect to the server.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool called `screen`. After you login to a server, just type `screen` and from now on your session will be running in a virtual terminal that `screen` provides, which means it will be "kept alive" and still running even if you close your terminal (but not if you type `exit` - this will terminate `screen` !). You can also purposefully disconnect from `screen` session by pressing Ctrl+A and then D while in `screen` session and the session will still be running. Then you can log out of the server.

As said in the comment, after reconnecting to the server type `screen -dr` and you should be reconnected to your session. If you had only one disconnected `screen` session, you don't need to type any arguments after `screen -dr`. Otherwise, you can list all `screen` sessions on your account with `screen -ls` and then type `screen -dr PID` where `PID` is the PID of the session you want.

It's not quite "saving" a session as you requested, because the session is **running all the time**, even after you disconnect, which means if you left some program running, it will continue to run and continue to write output - if any - to the virtual terminal. `screen` has a scrollback buffer, so if you press Ctrl+A and then Esc while in `screen` session, you can scroll back to see the lines of output the program produced while you were disconnected. But if there is lot of output, the scrollback buffer may be not enough.

`screen` can do much more - for example you can have multiple sessions running in background and switch between them, but the basic use case described above should be enough for what you need.